# Linking Error while integrating PayPal MPL in IOS

Tags: ios, paypal, linker-errors

I am integrating `PayPalMPL` in my IOS app.
After integration, it is working fine in IOS simulator but when i tried to run in external device i.e; in I-pad, then it shows an error which says

`ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/.../Library/libPayPalMPL.a file '/Users/.../Library/libPayPalMPL.a' for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Even the demo app is showing this error.

I have found many solutions regarding this but unable to resolve.

I am in Xcode 5 and running code in IOS 6 on my I-Pad.

P.S: I am using old [PayPalMPL](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL) instead of new [PayPal IOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) because i have to use Adaptive Payment which should include Refund, Chain Payments and Future Payments, which is lacking in the new SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the same question in the PayPal help forum and they replied

> Sorry to say but the only option here is you need to use the our
>   latest SDK to resolve this issue or try not to use any library which
>   discontinue in IOS.

Then when asked "I want to use Adaptive Payment which is not available in new SDK", then they replied,

> There is no specific solution for this. But you may remove the library
>   which not supported in IOS. We will some out with the new SDK soon.

At last I have to implement this from the server side.

Comment: Facing same problem, It is very bad that they have not updated this feature in new SDK

Answer (score 0):

Build Settings -> Set "Enable Bitcode" to "No" worked for me.